# Line integral of triangle

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been given the question: The vector field is
$$F(r) = (z^2 − y^2, x^2 − z^2, y^2 − x^2)$$
Let $C$ be the closed curve that is the boundary of the triangle with vertices at the points $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$. Specify a direction along $C$ and consider the closed-loop integral $F.dr$.

Explain why the contribution to the integral is the same from each edge of $C$, and evaluate the integral above.

I've parametrised the curve into three parts going anticlockwise.

- Path 1: From $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,1,0)$ where parameter $p(t)=(1-t,t,0)$ with $0<t<1$. So when I integrate it I do $F(p1(t))*(p'(t))dt$ from $0$ to $1$.
- path 2: $p2(t)=(0,1-t,t)$
- path 3: $p3(t)=(t,0,1-t)$

and did the same for each part.

However, each paths integral I've worked out isn't equal?

Not sure where I am making my mistake, have I understood the question correctly? I'd add my integration but I'm not familiar with latex, should I attach an image?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly is the vector field $\;F\;$ the claim is false.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry I missed it out. Now added.

Comment: Now write down what your work is, so as to find out mistakes...

Comment: Could I upload an image of my workings and link that, or must I learn latex to show what I have done?

Comment: @Talen It'd be better if you can upload it with MathJaX, but as you're a beginner (though you've been a member more than two years (!)), I guess you can also upload a link...

Answer (score 1):

With your notation:

$$\text{Path 1}\::\;\; F(p(t))=\left(-t^2,\,(1-t)^2,\,t^2-(1-t)^2\right)=\left(-t^2,\,(1-t)^2,\,2t-1\right)\implies $$

$$F(p(t))\cdot p'(t) =(-t^2, (1-t)^2, 2t-1)\cdot(-1,1,0)=2t^2-2t+1$$

and thus the first line integral becomes

$$\int_0^1 (2t^2-2t+1)\,dt=\left.\left(\frac23t^3-t^2+t\right)\right|_0^1=\frac23-1+1=\frac23$$

Check the others equal this one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be F(p(t))⋅p′(t) rather than F′(p(t))⋅p′(t)?

Comment: @Taleri Of course, you're right...and that's what I wrote, but did otherwise. Editing now.

Comment: I made calculation errors

Comment: @DonAntonio There's a typo in the antiderivative, $1/3$ instead of $2/3$.

Comment: @Maxim Good catch, thanks. Edited.